# PHP Dates: Syntax Debug on PHP if conditional

Tags: php, debugging, syntax, if-statement

In the following code $start is a start date manually entered into a datepicker and $end is a separate key also, entered via datepicker.  These are being compared against date('ymd'), which is today.

Early in the code for this plugin we have this code (where the same argument returns true):

```
//Parse End Date
if($end):
    $end = explode('-', $end);
    $end = mktime($hour, $_POST['_date_minute'], 0, $end[0], $end[1], $end[2]);
        if ((date('ymd',$start) < date('ymd',$end)) && (date('ymd',$end) >= date('ymd'))) {
            $compare = date('ymd'); //Overwrite start date $compare
        }
        else {
            $compare = date('ymd', $start);         
        }
endif;
```

**Later in the code, the same argument returns false here:**

```
function event_list_date($start_or_end, $format, $echo = true){
    global $post;

    // Check the end date, if it's greater than today and then start date is less than or equal to today, round it off so that it's today and doesn't look like the event is already past

    // Original Code
    //  if ((date('ymd',$start) < date('ymd',$end)) && (date('ymd',$end) >= time('ymd'))) {

    // Stackoverflow Proposed Change
    //  if ($start < $end && $end >= time('ymd')) {

    if ($start < $end && $end >= time('ymd')) {
        $start = date('ymd'); //Overwrite start date $compare
    }
    else {
        $start = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_date_start', true);;            
    }

    $end = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_date_end', true);

    if($start_or_end == 'start'):
        $date = date($format, $start);
        if($echo): echo $date; else: return $date; endif;
    elseif($start_or_end == 'end'):
        $date = date($format, $end);
        if($echo): echo $date; else: return $date; endif;
    endif;   
}
```

Can someone tell me why the if statement is returning false for an event with a $start value equal to yesterday and an $end equal to 5 days from now?

**EDIT: Posting a "zoomed out" context of this code**

Comment: In your 'zoomed out code', `$start` and `$end` are never defined.  Are these coming from `$post`?  It would be helpful if you specified what `$post` has for a value, and what the argument `$start_or_end` has for a value.

Comment: $post is coming from WordPress, this is defined in the WordPress core and the code posted is a plugin for WordPress :)

Comment: OKay.. can you post a `vardump` of `$post`?  And again... the `$start` and `$end` variables are not defined in the function `event_list_date`, which is a big part of the reason why the code does not work.

Comment: Chris, I finally figured it out.  $start is a key that is used frequently throughout the code. The problem was that in the code above I defined it in a "self-referencing" way.  When I fixed the early `$start` declaration in the function and renamed it to `$start_range_exception = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_date_start', true);` the circular logic was fixed and it worked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date function changes these into strings.  Then you're using mathematical comparison operators to compare the strings, which does not work in the way you're wanting.  If you want to compare a date against another date, you'll want to convert them to something more easily compared, like numbers.

`strtotime` will take care of that!  Since you're passing $start into `date()` (which requires a numeric argument), I assume $start is already a numeric time representation.  So, to compare against right now, use `time()`;

[strtotime docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[date docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: e.g., `$start < $end && $end >= time()`

Comment: Indeed, +1 for clarifying! :)

Comment: Thanks Chris!  Apologies for my PHP ineptitude :/  I've "zoomed out" my code because your proposed change is still returning false... sorry that I'm not able to find the reason!  Can you look at the more complete code?